# Rapid onChange causes OnClick not to register

Tags: reactjs

I set the state when I onChange of a input field and then have a submit function on the onClick. The onClick doesn't register at all if I click it within a second or so of the last input.

I have cut everything out of the component that I don't need and am left this:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Loader from '../utils/Loader';
import './CustomMenu.scss';
import {custom_getCategory} from '../../actions/customActions';
import propsDebug from '../utils/propsDebug';

class CustomMenu extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: "",
      customWords: [],
    }

  this.formToState = this.formToState.bind(this);
  this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);

}


formToState(e) {
  const {value, name} = e.target;
  this.setState({[name]: value});
}
submit() {
  const {input} = this.state;
  this.setState( state => {
    state.input = "";
  console.log("newState", state);
    return state;
  });
}

  render() {
    const {input, customWords} = this.state;


    return (
      <div className="CustomMenu">
        <input name="input" value={input} onChange={(e) => this.formToState(e)}/>
        <button onClick={(e) => {
          console.log("onClick");
          this.submit(e);
        }} style={{margin: "10px"}}>Add</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    data: state[ownProps.reduxState],
    custom: state.custom,
  })

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, {custom_getCategory})(CustomMenu);
```

Any ideas how I can fix this? I feel I have used this pattern many times before without issues - I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: Can't say for certain, but you are mutating the state directly in your submit function which is not recommended and can have strange side effects.  If you want to log the state after setting it, you can formulate your setState with a callback like so: ```this.setState({ input: ""}, () => console.log(this.state))```.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Its actually not directly mutated. The state is from the setState function. Maybe I should call it prevState or something.

Comment: Per [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), for a functional setState call "state is a reference to the component state at the time the change is being applied. It should not be directly mutated."  Still not sure if this will solve your issue but it's worth a shot.

Comment: No it didn't help but thank you for the lesson.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick={(e) => {
      console.log("onClick");
      this.submit(e);
    }} style={{margin: "10px"}}>Add</button>
```

I think the bug is from the callback you passed to your `onClick()`. You need to return the `this.submit()` before you can get it to fire.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick={(e) => (
  console.log("onClick");
  this.submit(e);
)} style={{margin: "10px"}}>Add</button>
```

use an implicit return instead.